# How do I properly put data from mysql inside <ul><li>?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Good day to you guys, I'm making a binary tree using php and mysql as my database. When fetching data from my database what I want is to put them inside ul and li's properly, indented properly.. [image: here]
as you can see it may seem perfectly fine and working as intended but when you inspect in dev tools you can see that it's not indented properly as some closing ul and li tags are missing.

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li><div><input type="checkbox">181210-1-105547-1</div>
            <ul>
                <li><div><input type="checkbox">181210-2-105603-2</div>
                <li><div><input type="checkbox">181210-3-105610-3</div>
                    <ul><li><div><input type="checkbox">181210-1-105614-4</div>
                        <ul><li><div><input type="checkbox">181210-2-105614-5</div>
                            <li><div><input type="checkbox">181210-3-105615-6</div>
                                </ul>
                                    <li><div><input type="checkbox">181210-3-105615-7</div>
                    </ul>
            </ul>   
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I come up to a solution about this?

here is my code

```
<style>
    .tree ul {
      padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

      transition: all 0.5s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .tree li {
        float: left; text-align: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        position: relative;
        padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }

    .tree li::before, .tree li::after{
        content: '';
        position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 50%; height: 20px;
    }
    .tree li::after{
        right: auto; left: 50%;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
        display: none;
    }

    .tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

    .tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
        border: 0 none;
    }
    .tree li:last-child::before{
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    }
    .tree li:first-child::after{
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    }
    .tree ul ul::before{
        content: '';
        position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 0; height: 20px;
    }
    .tree li div{
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #666;
        font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
        font-size: 11px;
        display: inline-block;

        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;

        transition: all 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .tree li div:hover, .tree li div:hover+ul li div {
        background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
    }
    .tree li div:hover+ul li::after, 
    .tree li div:hover+ul li::before, 
    .tree li div:hover+ul::before, 
    .tree li div:hover+ul ul::before{
        border-color:  #94a0b4;
    }
  </style>
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li><div><input type="checkbox">181210-1-105547-1</div>
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $name = 'argent';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' .$host .';dbname=' .$name;
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
    );
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

    function displayChildren($parent) {
        global $conn;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE sponsorUpline = ?');
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $parent);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($row = $stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<li><div><input type="checkbox">' .$row['serialNumber'] .'</div>';
                if(displayChildren($row['serialNumber'])) {
                    displayChildren($row['serialNumber']);
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }

    displayChildren('181210-1-105547-1');

?>  
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And [image: here] is my table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're only conditionally closing the `</li>` tag.

Try moving that `echo '<li/>';` outside the `if` blocks:

```
<?php
// from inside your  displayChildren function...
if($row = $stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<li><div><input type="checkbox">' .$row['serialNumber'] .'</div>';
        if(displayChildren($row['serialNumber'])) {
            displayChildren($row['serialNumber']);
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
// ...
```

Comment: Ohh.. that fixed it, I didn't see it till you point it out sir.. really fixed the problem.